# Attaching iso file to Azure VM

Tags: azure, iso, azure-powershell

I have a Powershell script that creates a Win 10 VM, and want to mount an ISO file to install software on it. I can make the ISO available through blob store.

How can i attach the ISO to the desktop in powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either download the ISO to the VM from blob and then mount it using Windows, or you could store it in Azure Files and mount the file share in Windows and then mount.

All of that said, you'd be better off looking at a more modern package installation system like Chocolatey or WinGet.